# R cannot be resolved - Android error 2 first one wasn't enough

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-11.04, phonegap-plugins

System:

Ubuntu 11.04 (up to date)
Eclipse SDK - Version: 3.7.1
Android Development Toolkit
Version: 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534

PhoneGap 1.3.0
PhoneGap Facebook Connect Plugin

Just was putting a little phone gap project and the R connot be resolved..

This is what i tried:

Deleted All my android projects:
Restarted... 
Started new project..

Tried Clean...
Rebuild...

REMOVED all import R attempts from auto orgnize...

Made sure correct xml file name are lowercase and changes are correct.. like i said new project

Deleted auto generated files so they could be rebuilt...

This is the code that is erroring...

```
    Drawable crossDrawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.close);
    mCrossImage.setImageDrawable(crossDrawable);
    /* 'x' should not be visible while webview is loading
     * make it visible only after webview has fully loaded
    */
    mCrossImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I made sure and updated everything... and looked for bug fixes..

I'm stumped i usally work though stuff (because thats how you learn) but my head hurts...

Help me out,
  Thanks,
    Roger

Comment: Take a look and make sure something isn't wrong in one of your XML files. If *any* of them contain an error, `R` won't be built. You might also try right clicking on the project and selecting Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties

Comment: Make sure you are importing your application R and not Android.R

Comment: jprofitt, i changed one line of xml  <plugin name="com.phonegap.facebook.Connect" value="com.phonegap.facebook.ConnectPlugin" /> and fix project didn't do anything

Comment: AJcodez, i am importing the application R that is autogenrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if any of your xml file is having error,if yes then correct xml then clean your project and then see.

then also error persists then check your installation if its proper or not 
then try running the project.

Comment: no xml files have errors... and the hello android app is fine and works... i guess the installation works..

Comment: <plugin name="com.phonegap.facebook.Connect" value="com.phonegap.facebook.ConnectPlugin" /> added this

Answer (score 6):

This could help someone save hours of time... on `FbDialog.java` you must add the following line on the beginning:

```
import com.package.your.R;
```

(or whatever is your android package so that your `R.java` will be imported to `FbDialog.java`)

Comment: "import com.mycompanyname.appname.*;" also does the job.

Comment: This fixed my problem. I noticed after the fact tt is called out very vaguely in the documentation for the Facebook cordova plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
       Drawable crossDrawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(com.yourpackagename.R.drawable.close);
```

I added

```
 int id = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("close", "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
Drawable crossDrawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(id);
```